# lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit / still not solved

Tags: boot, 16.04, mount

After upgrading ubuntu to 16 I get:
lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit

The (google) proposed solution is not working, it only ruins my display resolution.

---

```
/etc/default/grub, change:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset" Then add this line:
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial" 
Run sudo update-grub and reboot for the changes to take effect.
```

---

The booting process stops.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gives me a prompt
The disks are mounted read-only

after login I do a:

```
mount -o remount, rw /
```

the booting continues and the systems sometimes starts normal.

Any hints to a working solution are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

changed boot to upstart as default and everything is working okay now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)